# SDRAM interfacing problem with lpc4357

Tags: memory, interface, ram, sdram, lpc43xx

I am trying to interface SDRAM - AS4C8M16SA from Alliance, with LPC4357 (LQFP208 package). I'm not familiar with EMC or SDRAM. I got the RAM get initialized. But ,I cannot successfully write beyond 64 bytes into it. My connection details and initialization code are given below.

**SDRAM Details**

- Alliance AS4C8M16SA
- 128M - 8M x 16 bit , 2M word x 16-bit x 4-bank
- CAS Latency: 2, or 3
       Burst Length: 1, 2, 4, 8, or full page
       Burst Type:  Sequential or Interleaved
- 4096 refresh cycles/64ms

**Connections**

*SDRAM* -------------*LPC4357*

DQ0 - DQ15 -------EMC_D0 - EMC_D15

A0 - A11  -----------EMC_A1 - EMC_A12

BA0-----------------EMC_A13

BA1-----------------EMC_A14

RAS-----------------EMC_RAS

CAS-----------------EMC_CAS

CS------------------EMC_DYCS0

WE------------------EMC_WE

NC/RFU--------------NC

LDQM----------------EMC_DQMOUT0

UDQM----------------EMC_DQMOUT1

CLK-----------------EMC_CLK0

CKE-----------------EMC_CKEOUT0

***Note:*** EMC_A6, EMC_A7, EMC_A8 and EMC_A0 pins are connected to some pull-up circuits to select the ISP method. The connection picture is attached.
[image]

**Code**

```
void SDRAM_Init () {
    uint32_t pclk, temp;
    uint32_t tmpclk;
    TIM_TIMERCFG_Type TIM_ConfigStruct;

    /* Set up EMC pin */
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    0    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );    //A5
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    1    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );    //A6
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    2    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );    //A7
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    3    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );    //OE
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    4    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );    //BLS0
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    5    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );    //CS0
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    6    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );    //WE
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    7    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//D0
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    8    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//D1
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    9    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//D2
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    10    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//D3
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    11    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//D4
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    12    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//D5
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    13    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//D6
    scu_pinmux(    1    ,    14    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//D7
    scu_pinmux(    2    ,    0    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//A13
    scu_pinmux(    2    ,    1    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//A12
    scu_pinmux(    2    ,    2    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//A11
    scu_pinmux(    2    ,    6    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//A10
    scu_pinmux(    2    ,    7    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//A9
    scu_pinmux(    2    ,    8    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//A8
    scu_pinmux(    2    ,    9    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    0    );//A0// changed as GPIO
    scu_pinmux(    2    ,    10    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//A1
    scu_pinmux(    2    ,    11    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//A2
    scu_pinmux(    2    ,    12    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//A3
    scu_pinmux(    2    ,    13    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//A4
    scu_pinmux(    5    ,    0    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//D12
    scu_pinmux(    5    ,    1    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//D13
    scu_pinmux(    5    ,    2    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//D14
    scu_pinmux(    5    ,    3    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//D15
    scu_pinmux(    5    ,    4    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//D8
    scu_pinmux(    5    ,    5    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//D9
    scu_pinmux(    5    ,    6    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//D10
    scu_pinmux(    5    ,    7    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//D11
    scu_pinmux(    6    ,    1    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    1    );//DYCS1    
    scu_pinmux(    6    ,    3    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//CS1
    scu_pinmux(    6    ,    4    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//CAS
    scu_pinmux(    6    ,    5    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//RAS
    scu_pinmux(    6    ,    6    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    1    );//BLS1
    scu_pinmux(    6    ,    7    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    1    );//A15
    scu_pinmux(    6    ,    8    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    1    );//A14
    scu_pinmux(    6    ,    9    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//DYCS0
    scu_pinmux(    6    ,    10    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//DQMOUT1
    scu_pinmux(    6    ,    11    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//CKEOUT0
    scu_pinmux(    6    ,    12    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//DQMOUT0
    scu_pinmux(    10    ,    4    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//A23
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    0    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    2    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    3    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    4    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    5    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    6    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    7    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    8    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    9    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    10    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    12    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    13    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    11    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//CS3
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    14    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//DYCS2
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    15    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//A17
    scu_pinmux(    13    ,    16    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    2    );//A16
    scu_pinmux(    14    ,    0    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//A18
    scu_pinmux(    14    ,    1    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//A19
    scu_pinmux(    14    ,    2    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//A20
    scu_pinmux(    14    ,    3    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//A21
    scu_pinmux(    14    ,    4    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );//A22
    scu_pinmux(    14    ,    5    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );
    scu_pinmux(    14    ,    6    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );
    scu_pinmux(    14    ,    7    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );
    scu_pinmux(    14    ,    8    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );
    scu_pinmux(    14    ,    9    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );
    scu_pinmux(    14    ,    10    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );
    scu_pinmux(    14    ,    11    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );
    scu_pinmux(    14    ,    12    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );
    scu_pinmux(    14    ,    13    ,    MD_PLN_FAST    ,    3    );



    /* Select EMC clock-out */
    LPC_SCU->SFSCLK_0 = MD_PLN_FAST;
    LPC_SCU->SFSCLK_1 = MD_PLN_FAST;
    LPC_SCU->SFSCLK_2 = MD_PLN_FAST;
    LPC_SCU->SFSCLK_3 = MD_PLN_FAST;



    TIM_ConfigStruct.PrescaleOption = TIM_PRESCALE_USVAL;
    TIM_ConfigStruct.PrescaleValue    = 1;



    // Set configuration for Tim_config and Tim_MatchConfig
    TIM_Init(LPC_TIMER0, TIM_TIMER_MODE,&TIM_ConfigStruct);



    LPC_EMC->CONTROL     = 0x00000001;
    LPC_EMC->CONFIG      = 0x00000000;
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICCONFIG0    = 0<<19 | 1<<12 | 1<<10 | 1<<7; /* 128Mb, 8Mx16, 4 banks, row=12, column=9 */



    pclk = CGU_GetPCLKFrequency(CGU_PERIPHERAL_M4CORE);



    _DBG("pclk = ");
    _DBD32(pclk);

    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICRASCAS0    = 0x00000303; /* 1 RAS, 3 CAS latency */
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICREADCONFIG = 0x00000001; /* Command delayed strategy, using EMCCLKDELAY */



    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICRP         = NS2CLK(pclk, 20);
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICRAS        = NS2CLK(pclk, 42);
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICSREX       = NS2CLK(pclk, 63);
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICAPR        = 0x00000005;
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICDAL        = 0x00000005;
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICWR         = 2;
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICRC         = NS2CLK(pclk, 63);
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICRFC        = NS2CLK(pclk, 63);
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICXSR        = NS2CLK(pclk, 63);
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICRRD        = NS2CLK(pclk, 14);
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICMRD        = 0x00000002;



    TIM_Waitus(100);                           /* wait 100ms */
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICCONTROL    = 0x00000183; /* Issue NOP command */



    TIM_Waitus(200);                           /* wait 200ms */
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICCONTROL    = 0x00000103; /* Issue PALL command */


    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICREFRESH    = EMC_SDRAM_REFRESH(pclk,70); /* ( n * 16 ) -> 32 clock cycles */



    //for(i = 0; i < 0x80; i++);               /* wait 128 AHB clock cycles */
    TIM_Waitus(200);                           /* wait 200ms */



    tmpclk = (uint32_t)15625*(uint32_t)pclk/1000000000/16;
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICREFRESH    = tmpclk; /* ( n * 16 ) -> 736 clock cycles -> 15.330uS at 48MHz <= 15.625uS ( 64ms / 4096 row ) */



    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICCONTROL    = 0x00000083; /* Issue MODE command */



    //Timing for 48/60/72MHZ Bus
    temp = *((volatile uint32_t *) 0x28023000);//(SDRAM_ADDR_BASE | (0x23<<12)) );//(3<<4| 3)<<11)); /* 4 burst, 3 CAS latency */
    temp = temp;
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICCONTROL    = 0x00000000; /* Issue NORMAL command */



    //[re]enable buffers
    LPC_EMC->DYNAMICCONFIG0    |= 1<<19;

}
```

after init, i used this code

```
#define FRAMEBUFFER_ADDR        0x28000000

len = 64;

memcpy((uint8_t *)FRAMEBUFFER_ADDR,Buffer720,len);
```

This will successfully copy 64 bytes. Length above 64 is not working properly.

**Results**

The Reference text in Buffer720 is

*"Software that is described herein is for illustrative purposes only which provides customers with programming information regarding the products."*

**1. when copying 64 bytes**

***expected :***

*"Software that is described herein is for illustrative purposes o"*

***actual :***

*"Software that is described herein is for illustrative purposes o"*

**2. when copying 128 bytes**

***expected :***

*"Software that is described herein is for illustrative purposes only which provides customers with programming information regard"*

***actual :***

*"ed herei describ described hereirposes oative puative purposes omers wites custoes customers witn regardf
ormatioformation regard "*

Also, if the code is like this, I can copy upto 256 Bytes.

```
len = 64;

    for( i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        memcpy((uint8_t *)FRAMEBUFFER_ADDR+(i*64),Buffer720+(i*64),len);



        memcmp(FrameBuff,(uint8_t *)FRAMEBUFFER_ADDR+(i*64),len);



    }
```

ie, if reading the values after each 64 bytes, it can copy upto 256 Bytes.

What is wrong in this? Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Describe the symptoms. Does it catch fire? Something a little less exciting? Do you read all 0's? All 1's? Random values?

Comment: @brhans Thank u for  pointing out the mistake. I have added the missing details. Please check it.